# 404 error on swagger UI with Spring webflux

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, spring-webflux

I am trying to include swagger to spring boot web flux application. I have included the below code in the config file. It was working fine. But now it is not working with the error

> f90bda5c-2] There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found,
> status=404). org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException:
> 404 NOT_FOUND     at
> org.springframework.web.reactive.resource.ResourceWebHandler.lambda$handle$0(ResourceWebHandler.java:325)
> Suppressed:
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:  Error has
> been observed at the following site(s):   |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET
> "/swagger-ui.html" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler] Stack trace:         at
> org.springframework.web.reactive.resource.ResourceWebHandler.lambda$handle$0(ResourceWebHandler.java:325)

```
***@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebFlux
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .genericModelSubstitutes( Mono.class, Flux.class, Publisher.class)
            .select()
            .paths( PathSelectors.any())
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui.html**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
}***
```

I removed the addResourceHandlers method and tried, but it is still not loading /swagger-ui.htmlwith and gives the same 404 error.

What is the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

There was a change in the Swagger-UI module. If you're using 3.0.0 snapshot and using spring boot, [follow these instructions](https://github.com/springfox/springfox#migrating-from-earlier-snapshot). The url should be available @ [/context-path]/swagger-ui/index.html

Comment: After following the instaruction mentioned in the above link you mentioned, the error is localhost refused to connect. url used is http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked with the following code:

```
 @EnableWebFlux
 public class SwaggerConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {
     @Bean
     public Docket api() {
         return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
             .genericModelSubstitutes( Mono.class, Flux.class, Publisher.class)
             .select()
             .paths( PathSelectors.any())
         .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
             .build();
     }
 }
```